# Picturing the discrete metric?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A chapter on topology talks about this and asks me to "think of a model for the discrete metric on $M$" where $M$ may have $1, 2, 3, 4$ points. Here is what I think:

$2$ points = $2$ distinct points

$3$ points = equilateral triangle

$4$ points = tetrahedron

$1$ point = ??? A point by itself? But that would mean $1 = 0$...

The book goes on to say "imagine the discrete metric on $\mathbb{R}$", which I'm unable to grasp. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Imagining the discrete metric on $\mathbb R$ is a good way to make your head explode.  You require an uncountable number of points an equal length apart from each other. Even trying to imagine $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb Q$ under the discrete metric becomes difficult.

I should also ask: what would the discrete topology on a set of 5 points look like?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with one point by itself.

Comment: Wouldn't this discrete topology be the 'complete graph' ?

Comment: Just imagine a continuous-dimensional simplex.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure, why do you think about objects from continuous geometry, the following example shall work I guess. A finite graph is a finite set $V$ of points, and $E\subseteq V\times V$ are edges of this graph. We can endow $V$ with a metric by
$$
  d(x,y) = n\in \Bbb N_0\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \text{any path from }x\text{ to }y\text{ passes at least }n\text{ edges}
$$

The graph is called fully connected if $E = V\times V$. Then $d$ brings a discrete topology on a fully connected graph: from any point on such graph, you can reach any *other* point passing by only $1$ edge. If there is only one point, of course you don't have to move anywhere.

Comment: I see this is a very old post. But I really liked this kind of concept. I would really love to know more about this. Can you please tell me more about this field, or simply suggest me a reference or something.

Comment: @user398623 graph theory?

Comment: Graph theory? Really? And exactly which part of graph theory it is? Is Continuos Geometry as you mentioned  a part of Graph Theory?

Comment: @user398623: which exactly concept did you like?

Comment: I couldn't visualize the concept fully. That's why I was asking for some reference. Exactly when you said that we could reach any other passing by only 1 edge.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Stop imagining your topologies as belonging to Euclidean space. If you were going to imagine a discrete metric on $\mathbb{R}$ by visualizing the placement in $\mathbb{R}^3 $, there simply wouldn't be any room!

In the case of $ \mathbb{R} $, imposing the discrete metric just results in a case where every point $ x \neq y $ is of distance 1 away from each other. It just refers to the points being "separated", you're not meant to visualize the points separated in Euclidean space.

Comment: See Frank McGovern's comment for why this is a bad idea.