# Statement about the discrete (metric) space, and both an open and closed ball.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I have the following statement from my notes:

*"Let $(X,d)$ be the **discrete space** i.e. any non-empty set with the discrete metric ($d_d(x,y)=1$ for all $x\neq y$). Then, amazingly, $B_1(x)=\{x\}$, a set consisting only of $x$, and $\tilde B_1(x)=X.$"*

With the **discrete space** $(X,d)$, being the set $X$ with the **discrete metric** defined on it as,

$d_d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$

and,

$d_d(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$

We also have $B_1(x)$, the **open ball** centered at $x$ with radius $1$, and $\tilde B_1(x)$ the **closed ball** centered at $x$ of radius $1$.

This is what I have so far to verify the first part of the statement (note, I am **not** asking how to show/prove this statement, so please bear with me):

Our open ball, $B_1(x)$, can be written equivalently as,

$$B_1(x)=\{y\in X:d(x,y)\lt1\}$$

And we know that the boundary of our ball will be all $y$ satisfying,

$$d(x,y)=1$$

So then $y$, intuitively, is **on** the boundary of the sphere, (and hence, not **in** the sphere) and $x\neq y$. This leaves us with the case of $x=x$. From the properties of a metric space, we know that,

$$d(x,x)=0$$

And of course,

$$0<1\implies x\in B_1(x)$$

Now here comes my first question; how is it that an open ball of radius $1$ can have only one element? I am finding it hard to conceptualize that this is the only element in the set. Can anybody help me to visualize this better and understand it more clearly?

Could somebody also help me to clarify, in a similar fashion, the second part of the statement regarding the closed ball, namely that $\tilde B_1(x)=X$?

Is the point that I am finding hard to grasp as simple as supposing that $x$ and $y$ are the only elements in $X$?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332179/picturing-the-discrete-metric?

Comment: It's not true that $x$ and $y$ are the only elements in $X$. 

For an arbitrary element $x \in X$, what $B_1(x)=\{x\}$ means is that the only element that is within a distance of $1$ of $x$ is $x$ itself, and what $\tilde B_1(x)=X$ means is that all elements in $X$ are within $1$ of $x$, or, since $x$ was arbitrary, that all elements of $X$ are within $1$ of each other. It all follows from the definition of the discrete metric.

Comment: the topological boundary of the open ball is empty, no point belongs to it, as the ball, in the above context, is both open and closed. Re how to visualize, think of your space as of the vertices of an equilateral triangle in the plane (at least you get an example with 3 points), of course you could also visualize a 4-point example as the vertices of a regular tetrahedron in three-dimensional Euclidean space. The ball has only one element, as there is void where you would expect the other elements.